# How to recursively delete a folder with the files within using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to delete a folder in FTP and it's files recursively.

Any example code do I can implement?

Comment: I have just posted an answer there in this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797508/c-sharp-how-can-ftpclient-delete-a-directory/22623620#22623620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice Little example you can find here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

In the example they used `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile` class to direct what kind of operation they want to do.

Use the WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory method once you have a handle on the parent directory you want to delete:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.aspx

Answer (score 14):

First you have to list all your files in your directory :

```
public static List<string> DirectoryListing(string Path, string ServerAdress, string Login, string Password)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ServerAdress + Path);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;            

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            result.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Then you need a method to delete a single file (because you can delete a folder only if it's empty) :

```
public static void DeleteFTPFile(string Path, string ServerAdress, string Login, string Password)
    {
        FtpWebRequest clsRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ServerAdress + Path);
        clsRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password);

        clsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

        string result = string.Empty;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)clsRequest.GetResponse();
        long size = response.ContentLength;
        Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(datastream);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        datastream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

And finally :

```
public static void DeleteFTPDirectory(string Path, string ServerAdress, string Login, string Password)
{
        FtpWebRequest clsRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ServerAdress + Path);
        clsRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password);

        List<string> filesList = DirectoryListing(Path, ServerAdress, Login, Password);

        foreach (string file in filesList)
        {
            DeleteFTPFile(Path + file, ServerAdress, Login, Password);
        }

        clsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;

        string result = string.Empty;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)clsRequest.GetResponse();
        long size = response.ContentLength;
        Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(datastream);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        datastream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

You can easily call this like that (for me those methods are in a class called "Ftp") :

Ftp.DeleteFTPDirectory(the_path_of_your_folder_in_ftp,your_server_address,your_ftp_login,your_ftp_password);

Of course, you'll need to customize those lines, but it worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 5):

There's no support for recursive operations in the [`FtpWebRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) (or any other FTP implementation in the .NET framework). You have to implement the recursion yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, deleting files and recursing into subdirectories (listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the `FtpWebRequest`. The `FtpWebRequest` unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for a file and to succeed for directory (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name". If that succeeds, it's a file, if that fails, it's a directory. But that can become a performance problem, when you have a large number of entries.
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format).
- In this specific case, you can just try to delete the entry as a file. If deleting fails, try to list the entry as a directory. If the listing succeeds, you assume it's a folder and proceed accordingly. Unfortunately some servers do not error, when you try to list a file. They will just return a listing with a single entry for the file.

```
static void DeleteFtpDirectory(string url, NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    listRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream listStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(listStream))
    {
        while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] tokens =
          line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string name = tokens[8];
        string permissions = tokens[0];

        string fileUrl = url + name;

        if (permissions[0] == 'd')
        {
            DeleteFtpDirectory(fileUrl + "/", credentials);
        }
        else
        {
            FtpWebRequest deleteRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
            deleteRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
            deleteRequest.Credentials = credentials;

            deleteRequest.GetResponse();
        }
    }

    FtpWebRequest removeRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    removeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;
    removeRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    removeRequest.GetResponse();
}
```

The `url` should be like `ftp://example.com/directory/to/delete/`

---

Or use a 3rd party library that supports recursive operations.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can delete whole directory with a single call to [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles):

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Delete folder
    session.RemoveFiles("/home/user/foldertoremove").Check();
}
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions really worked on different types of servers except using
[System.Net.FtpClient](https://netftp.codeplex.com/)

```
 using System.Net.FtpClient;
 static void DeleteFtpDirectoryAndContent(string host, string path, NetworkCredential credentials, string dontDeleteFileUrl)
    {
        using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient())
        {
            conn.Host = host;
            conn.Credentials = credentials;

            foreach (FtpListItem item in conn.GetListing(path, FtpListOption.AllFiles | FtpListOption.ForceList))
            {

                switch (item.Type)
                {
                    case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory:
                        conn.DeleteDirectory(item.FullName, true, FtpListOption.AllFiles | FtpListOption.ForceList);
                        break;
                    case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File:
                        if (!dontDeleteFileUrl.EndsWith(item.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            conn.DeleteFile(item.FullName);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```